# Qt- How to streamline application by executing a resource intensive task in a different thread

Tags: multithreading, qt

I am creating a music library app using Qt( C++). It involves a method that does the following jobs in the given sequence-

1. List **N** audio files by recursively traversing a directory.
2. Read each and every file to collect ID3 tags.
3. Extract artwork images from the files.
4. Save the ID3 tags in the database.

The above set of tasks are extremely resource intensive. For **N ~ 1000**, it takes around a minute and half to complete the tasks and during the course of execution of this sequence, the GUI freezes up and doesn't respond well as I currently use no other threads.

I have seen a few examples of Qt threading and they more or less tell how to do things in parallel as expected but in those examples, achieving parallelism or concurrency is a requirement as they don't have any other options. But in case of my app, it's a choice whether I use multiple threads or not. The goal is to make sure the GUI stays responsive and interactive during the execution of the resource intensive task.I would really appreciate any expert advice may be with a code template or example in Qt to perform the resource intensive task in a different thread.

Code in main thread-

```
QStringList files;
QString status;
createLibrary(files, status);            //To be done in a different thread

if(status == "complete"){
    //do something
}
```

Thanks a lot your time!

Comment: This can give you insight in Qt threading: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects and staying responsive.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the QtConcurrent module.

Use [QtConcurrent::map()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtconcurrent/qtconcurrent.html#map) to iterate over the list of files and call a method in separate thread:

```
QFuture<void> result = QtConcurrent::map(files, createLibrary);
```

[QFutureWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfuturewatcher.html) will send a signal when the processing is done:

```
QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), 
        this, SLOT(processingFinished()));

// Start the computation.
QFuture<void> result = QtConcurrent::map(files, createLibrary);
watcher.setFuture(result);
```

BTW because of a lot of bad files in the wild, the music player Amarok decided to put the id3 tag scanner in a separate process. See [here](http://amaroklive.com/blog/archives/76-Inside-amaroK-1.4-Collection-Scanner.html) for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

My best advice would be to create a subclass `QThread`.  Pass this subclass a pointer to the directories and give it a pointer to a valid (non-null) view that you want to update in the following way:

header.h

```
class SearchAndUpdate : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SearchAndUpdate(QStringList *files, QWidget *widget);
    //The QWidget can be replaced with a Layout or a MainWindow or whatever portion
    //of your GUI that is updated by the thread.  It's not a real awesome move to
    //update your GUI from a background thread, so connect to the QThread::finished()
    //signal to perform your updates.  I just put it in because it can be done.
    ~SearchAndUpdate();
    QMutex mutex;
    QStringList *f;
    QWidget *w;
    bool running;
private:
    virtual void run();
};
```

Then in your implementation for that thread do this:

thread.cpp

```
SearchAndUpdate(QStringList *files, QWidget *widget){
     this->f=files;
     this->w=widget;
}

void SearchAndUpdate::run(){
    this->running=true;
    mutex.lock();

    //here is where you do all the work
    //create a massive QStringList iterator
    //whatever you need to complete your 4 steps.
    //you can even try to update your QWidget *w pointer
    //although some window managers will yell at you

    mutex.unlock();
    this->running=false;
    this->deleteLater();
}
```

Then in your GUI thread maintain the valid pointers `QStringList *files` and `SearchAndUpdate *search`, then do something like this:

```
files = new QStringList();
files->append("path/to/file1");
...
files->append("path/to/fileN");
search = new SearchAndUpdate(files,this->ui->qwidgetToUpdate);
connect(search,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(threadFinished()));
search->start();

...

void threadFinished(){
    //update the GUI here and no one will be mad
}
```

Comment: I did exactly how you've instructed but ended up having `error: undefined reference to worker::start()' `. Any Idea what it could be? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Killswitch here are some things to check: make sure you `#include <QThread>`, and don't override the `start()` method only override the `run()` method.  The [start()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#start) method is inherited from `QThread` and basically calls run() for you.